# HTML/CSS: How to make a text inside a div centered automatically

Tags: html, css

This might be a dumb question, but I am having a hard time figuring this out. I have some dynamic content that can vary in height. Below this, I have a row of static images but with dynamic texts attached to the image. I want to attach the text to the div in the center, and whenever the dynamic content ABOVE changes, it will push down this div accordingly, with the text fixed in the center. I also want a text fixed onto the right side. Right now, I have manually set the text in the center but this obviously does not work because whenever the screen or content changes, the image is pushed down, but not the text.

https://jsfiddle.net/t1z4tn47/2/

```css
#text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 540px;
  top: 100px;
}

#number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 470px;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="somecontent">
  some dynamic content here, height will vary and always push the wrapper div below
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="https://twibbon.s3.amazonaws.com/2012/82/d78470a4-3812-4faf-bfc8-e525d02378d1.png" alt="">
  <span id="text">HELLO</span>
  <span id="number">#1</span>
</div>

<img src="http://www.callrail.com/wp-content/upload/2016/05/Yellow-200x200.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Can you please make it a stack snippet? Edit your question, then cut the html from the question and click the button in the toolbar. Paste your html there, as well as the css. I can't access jsfiddle from here, and I thoroughly confused what you want to center, and on which axis.

Answer (score 0):

You may use translate transform after set the position of text
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

```css
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
#text{
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#number{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#wrapper{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**edit to match comments below**

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t1z4tn47/8/

I added `position: relative;` to the wrapper, this will let you change the absolute positioning of the child elements RELATIVE to the wrapper. Thus, if you add text on top and the boxes move down, the number and text will move with it.

```
#text{
  position:absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-right: -26px; 
}

#number{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#wrapper{
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I want the "HELLO" to be in the middle of the blue image, and "#1" on the top right of the blue image

Comment: It'll only work for texts with the same size, but that's the idea. You can use `text-align: center;` to auto center texts.

Comment: @IanRamos not on absolute positioned elements.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith You just need to set `width: 100%;`.